# How to call Page.Databind() without affecting other controls like gridview

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I am having a weird problem. My pages were working (too much data centric) before I needed to implement some javascript UI. Since these UI are required on many pages I referenced them on my masterpage like the following :-

```
 <link href="<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~")%>StenliStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~")%>js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~")%>js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the moment I added  Page.DataBind(); in load event of master page all gridview also started getting binded.
Since I am binding my grid view dynamically and binding them again during post back slow my pages. 
How can I stop this behaviour ? I need to use Page.ResolveUrl due to folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `Page.DataBind()` to resolve client url on master page. Try to resolve
links with the following way:

```
<link href="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/StenliStyle.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```